# How can I re-export items in a crate from a local module?

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a CLI tool and within my source I want to create a module, as a seperate file, to neatly wrap the CLI argument parsing logic.

My wrapper uses an external crate to do the actual CLI parsing however, despite re-exporting the items from the crate in my module, the consumer must use both `mod args;` and `use args::*;` in order for them to access the items from the crate.

For example:

I have the following structure:

```
src/
  main.rs
  args/
    mod.rs
```

I am using the `clap` crate to parse the CLI arguments in `args/mod.rs`

```rust
pub use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
pub struct Cli {
    #[arg(short, long)]
    pub name: String,
}
```

Then in `main.rs`, I attempt to use it

```rust
mod args;

fn main() {
    let cli = args::Cli::parse();
    println!("Hello {}!", cli.name);
}
```

The compiler errors with:

```
no function or associated item named `parse` found for struct `Cli` in the current scope items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
```

This can be resolved by using both `mod args` and `use args::*` like so:

```rust
mod args;
use args::Parser;

fn main() {
    let cli = args::Cli::parse();
    println!("Hello {}!", cli.name);
}
```

It's quite likely that a large number of my local modules will use external crates and require re-exporting some items. I would like to avoid consumers needing to have two import statements.

Is there a way to use one import statement when consuming modules?

Comment: Well you can always do `let cli = <args::Cli as args::Parser>::parse();` but other than that no, you need to import a trait in the current scope if you want to call the methods it defines.

Comment: `mod args` is not an import statement. It's a declaration of a submodule. `use` is an import statement, and you can avoid having many by using wildcard imports.

Answer (score 1):

In order to **call a function from a trait** (`clap::Parser`), **the trait itself must be explicitly imported or named**. It doesn't matter whether the trait is imported from its original source or from a re-export, but it must be imported. The typical place this comes up is methods (`some_value.some_trait_method()`) but it also applies to `SomeType::some_trait_function()`.

The code you have,

```rust
mod args;
use args::Parser;
```

is the minimum possible code to make `Cli::parse()` succeed. However, if you'd like to keep the imports slim at the price of verbosity of the implementation, you can explicitly name any trait function using the `<Type as Trait>` syntax:

```rust
let cli = <args::Cli as args::Parser>::parse();
```

The reason Rust has this rule is so that trait implementations cannot **globally** introduce new method or associated item names that might conflict with other ones; the trait in question must be in scope for the code calling it.